# maps from labelled configuration space to section space / iterated loop space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads, loop-spaces, configuration-spaces

In the paper [Mapping class group and function spaces: a survey, F. Cohen, M.A. Maldonado, 2014](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2200v2.pdf), page 3, Section 3:

for a $m$-manifold $M$, consider the disc bundle $D(M)$ in the tangent bundle $T(M)$,
and define $\dot T(M)$ by the identification of two vectors that lie in the same fibre and outside $D(M)$. 
This gives a $S^m=D^m/\partial D^m$-bundle $\dot T(M)\to M$.

For a pointed topological space $X$, denote by $\dot T(M;X)$ the fibrewise smash product of the bundle $\dot T(M)\to M$ with $X$ to obtain a bundle 
$$
\dot T(M;X)\to M$$
with fibre $S^m\wedge X=\Sigma^mX$.

Let $\Gamma(M;X)$ be the space of sections of $\dot T(M;X)$.

**Question:** When $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^m$, I want to prove (as given in [The homology of $\mathcal{C}_{n+1 }$–spaces, $n ≥ 0$. F. Cohen](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf), page 225)
$$
\Gamma(\mathbb{R}^m;X)\simeq \Omega^m\Sigma^mX.
$$
How to prove this?

I have tried but failed: 
$$
\Omega^m\Sigma^m X=\Omega^m(S^m\wedge X)=\text{Map}_*(S^m,S^m\wedge X),
$$
$$
\Gamma(\mathbb{R}^m;X)=\text{Map}(\mathbb{R}^m,S^mX).
$$
They are different.

Comment: I agree with your calculation. However I'm pretty sure that $\Gamma$ ought to denote the sections with compact support (i.e. the sections that coincide with the base point outside a compact space). In that case the formula $\Gamma(\mathbb{R}^m;X)\simeq \Omega^m\Sigma^mX$ is correct.

Comment: Under the assumption that $\Gamma$ is the collection of cross-sections with compact support,
I still have difficulties.
$$\Gamma(\mathbb{R}^n;X)=\{f\in \text{Map}(\mathbb{R}^n, S^n\wedge X)\mid f \text{ has compact support}\}\\=\{f\in \text{Map}(\mathbb{R}^n\cup\infty, S^n\wedge X)\mid \text{ outside a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, } f \text{ takes values at base point } *\}
$$ On the other hand, $$
\Omega^n\Sigma^nX=\text{Map}(S^n,S^n\wedge X)\\
=\{f\in \text{Map}(\mathbb{R}^n\cup \infty, S^n\wedge X)\mid f(\infty)=*\}
$$  (continued)

Comment: If $ \text{ outside a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, } f \text{ takes values at base point } *$, then $f(\infty)=*$. However the converse is not true. Hence 
$$
\Gamma(\mathbb{R}^n;X)\subsetneq \Omega^n\Sigma^nX.
$$
Since they are not equal, how to show that they are homotopy equivalent?

Comment: @GeoffroyHorel. Dear Prof. Horel, thanks so much. How to solve the difficulty as in the following answer?